# IOS facebook "single sign on" confirmation

Tags: ios, facebook, single-sign-on, confirmation

We are developing an server-client IOS app. And we have facebook single-sign-on option. Our IOS app is basically the client side of our program. What I want to learn is, if our server gets a login request via SSO how I can check the authenticity of the request. Can I check the validity of the FB token or something else?

Answer (score 0):

We handled this by allowing the client to auth the user.  Then POSTing the Facebook access_token to the server and doing a lookup on the user's email or facebookid in our database.